# upgrade golang in ubuntu but still shows old version

Tags: ubuntu, go

I have upgraded golang from version 1.6 to 2.6 in ubuntu with this command : `sudo apt dist-upgrade golang`
but when I run `go version` it still shows old version.
how I can make ubuntu to use newer version?

Comment: I think the latest Go is 1.9.something, `2.6` seems impossible.

Comment: Try the steps outlined here: https://askubuntu.com/a/755392

Comment: @mkopriva: Run `$ sudo apt show golang`. Output: `Package: golang  Version: 2:1.6-1ubuntu4`.

Comment: @peterSO fair enough, but that seems to be the version of the apt package for golang, not of golang itself.

Comment: @mkopriva: The question said `sudo apt dist-upgrade golang`.

Comment: 1. There is no Go 2.6.  2. The best way to install Go, even on Ubuntu/Debian, is to follow the [official Go instructions](https://golang.org/doc/install), rather than using the package manager.

Answer (score 2):

Run `sudo apt purge golang` to remove your current installation.

Follow the Go [Getting Started](https://golang.org/doc/install) instructions to install a current, supported version of Go.